# error: git-upload-pack died of signal 13

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a GitLab server (6.7.2) in Mac OS X 10.9.2, with git 1.9.2. There are two repositories. One can be cloned successfully, but the other fails as

```
$ git clone http://*/gamil/gamil.git
Cloning into 'gamil'...
remote: Counting objects: 426, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (375/375), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

And I checked `unicorn.stderr.log` in GitLab and found

```
I, [2014-04-21T23:03:58.761225 #4929]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2014-04-21T23:03:58.764556 #4940]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2014-04-21T23:03:58.766098 #4941]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
error: git-upload-pack died of signal 13
```

What does this error come from? How to fix it? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**:

I checked the repository:

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (426/426), done.
```

So it seems everything is fine, but can't clone into local computer.

**EDIT 2**:

I have updated GitLab to 6.8 with no luck.

**EDIT 3**:

I can clone the problematic repository through `ssh` protocol` as

```
$ git clone dongli@<...>:gamil
Cloning into 'gamil'...
remote: Counting objects: 426, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (317/317), done.
remote: Total 426 (delta 89), reused 426 (delta 89)
Receiving objects: 100% (426/426), 821.19 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (89/89), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

**EDIT 4**:

I checked the timeout in `unicorn.rb`:

```
# nuke workers after 30 seconds instead of 60 seconds (the default)
timeout 300
```

and the configuration for `nginx`:

```
# if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
# then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
location @gitlab {
  proxy_read_timeout 300; # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
  proxy_connect_timeout 300; # Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
  proxy_redirect     off;

  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  proxy_pass http://gitlab;
}
```

**EDIT 5**

I have uploaded the repository to GitHub, and the clone is OK:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dongli/GAMIL.git 1
Cloning into '1'...
remote: Counting objects: 355, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (308/308), done.
remote: Total 355 (delta 35), reused 355 (delta 35)
Receiving objects: 100% (355/355), 809.75 KiB | 244.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (35/35), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

So the repository is GOOD.

Comment: "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly" - `http://whatever.wherever.foo` closed the connection for some reason.

Comment: How can I diagnose the reason? Actually, the server `unicorn` said `error: git-upload-pack died of signal 13`.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but it seems to me like a timeout is breaking the connection.  Though, that does seem somewhat unlikely.

Comment: Edit unicorn.rb and increase `timeout` to something greater than `30`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the reason for my problem by looking inside `/var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log` which complains

```
2014/04/27 17:25:21 [crit] 14331#0: *19 open() 
"/usr/local/var/run/nginx/proxy_temp/3/00/0000000003" failed (13: Permission denied)
while reading upstream, client: 123.113.33.131, server: *, request:
"POST /gamil/gamil.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://unix:/Users/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket:/gamil/gamil.git/git-upload-pack", host: "*"
```

The directory `/usr/local/var` whose access permission is

```
drwx------    8 dongli  admin    272  4  1 14:55 var
```

So I changed it to

```
drwxr-x---    8 dongli  admin    272  4  1 14:55 var
```

Then the error is gone finally.

Comment: This is unlikely the issue, especially if smaller repositories work successfully.